# Error 127 to compile 'Makefile'

Tags: compilation, makefile

I'm very new to Linux and I'm using UBUNTU to run a code! when I use 'make' command to compile my 'Makefile' I get this error:

```
make:*** [mod_param.o] Error 127
```

could anyone tell me what is this error and why this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the Makefile?

Comment: What compiler are you trying to use?  Is it in your PATH? Does the compile command for mod_param.o work if you type it in manually at the command line?  Possibly, you don't have a compiler installed or available to the make process.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever reading the output of a build, you want to go up and find the FIRST error message.  That's almost always the important one.  Once something fails, the rest of the errors might be cascading problems from the first one.  In this case, that message is just make telling you that it tried to compile mod_param.c and it didn't work.  You'll have to look at the messages BEFORE this one to see why the compile failed.